# Shopping cart rule actions to stop sale items being discounted

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I have a coupon code currently set that applies 10% off an order. I would like to be able to set the actions so that the items i have in the sale category will not be allowed to be applied at checkout. Currently the rule allows the coupon to be applied to both sale and non sale items. 
I ultimately would like a customer to only be able to get the 10% discount on the non sale items at checkout even if they have both a sale and non sale item in the cart.

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can choose what products your rule affect by going under **Actions** and then the lower fieldset **Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions**

Here you can do the same kind of ruling as you can up under conditions meaning you can set it up so the rule is not applied to products from a specific category.

Use the **does not contain** or **is not one of**, I always get those two mixed up.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I have tried the suggested above of category does not contain in the actions section this does not work . I am more interested in the actual condition needed for the action section. Thanks,
Mike